# How can I send gif or video without users uploading using telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
elif message.text == 'Test':
            video = open('static/ct_ramp.mkv','rb')
            await message.answer_video(video)
            video.close()
```

I use aiogram and this code to sending my video but I should upload it to see
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcYjg.png

How can I send it and see it right now?

Comment: I know nothing about Telegram bots, but from reading your code, you could try ```await message.answer_video(video.read())```

Comment: *"without user uploading"* / *".. but i should upload it to see"* Please clarify the problem, it's hard to see the actual question

Comment: Are you trying to send it from a url instead of local file?

Comment: No, I send it from my local file

Comment: @SiddharthDushantha that wouldn't work, the answer_video function expects a file stream and this is meant to be sent as a response in an asynchronous instant message application. So the video can really only be played in the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Each user must configure their own Telegram client for automatic downloading of media. You or your bot can't force that in the user side.

What you can do is configure your own Telegram client (android, desktop, etc.) to use automatic download of videos, then the [autoplay](https://telegram.org/blog/autoplay) feature will work for big size videos **for you**.